# Is there any sample for AD B2C Integration with Google Recaptcha V3

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Any sample to integrate AD B2C Custom Policy with recaptcha V3, I could see integration with recpatcha v2 sample however looking for v3

Answer (score 4):

[This Azure AD B2C sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/captcha-integration) demonstrates integration of Azure AD B2C with the reCAPTCHA v2 API but it shouldn't be difficult to modify both [the client-side code](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/captcha-integration/source-code/Captcha-HTML-Page-Customisation/customCaptcha.html) and [the server-side code](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/8d7ed77c87298e83f1549257d4a16f6fa7355231/policies/captcha-integration/Captcha-Handler-API/Contoso.AADB2C.API/Controllers/IdentityController.cs#L20) to [the reCAPTCHA v3 API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3).

Comment: I see a challenge in passing the token set as hidden field to the Custom Policy Claim

Comment: You can submit the reCAPTCHA token using: `grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'registrationpage'}).then(function(token) { $('#g-recaptcha-response-toms').val(token); }`

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/650dbb2ddacb8fe8dd1fde34c33f4db9990b7812/policies/captcha-integration/policy/Captcha_TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L12) for the claim declaration of **g-recaptcha-response-toms** and [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/650dbb2ddacb8fe8dd1fde34c33f4db9990b7812/policies/captcha-integration/policy/Captcha_TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L83) for reference to it as an output claim on the self-asserted page UI.

Comment: You have used microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:selfasserted contract instead of unifiedssp and explicitly gave signup and forgot password link. Can we not use the unifiedssp here , as it has inbuilt signin and forgot pass links

Comment: Hi @Aparna Are you adding reCAPTCHA to your sign-in page are you?