# RECAPTCHA V3 IN SINGIN AD-B2C WITH USER FLOW

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, recaptcha-v3, azure-ad-b2c

I hope you can help me, azure b2c only let me integrate captcha on registration but not on login, i have been searching about integrate captcha v3 in login (AD-B2C) - user flow,  and I only have little time.
I found this,
[Is there any sample for AD B2C Integration with Google Recaptcha V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034326/is-there-any-sample-for-ad-b2c-integration-with-google-recaptcha-v3)
but I only need add captcha in my login(AD-B2C)user flow but not to change all my flow with custom policy, because Already I have my user flow with setting,
Please. can help me or share me any example please, actually I use he username and password to login in b2c,

**Thanks !!!**

Answer (score 0):

There is this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-node-sign-up-user-flow-captcha) that does not use custom policies but it's V2.

You'll have to modify it for V3.

Comment: Hi, yes, I thought of using this repository for my login, if I use it I will have to modify my javascript and I have been searching and I concluded that any developer with bad intentions could modify my javascript and bypass my captcha, maybe I am wrong, I am junior in javascript, my app should be very secure, what do you will recomended ? any   advice

Comment: azure b2c only let me integrate captcha on registration but not on login, for that I say it, My captcha on login will be only ornament, that I believe